# Does Devise allow us to consolidate logins across FB, twitter, Google to be seen as a single user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Does Devise allow to consolidate logins across FB, twitter, Google to be seen as a single user?

I am using devise gem(Omniauth) to login with Facebook, twitter and google credentials. The user may login with any of the above credentials. The user may login at 12p.m with google credentials and the same user at 3p.m with twitter credentials. Is there any possible way for devise to identify the same user logged in at 12p.m and 3p.m?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Devise can be used to consolidate logins using multiple social networking authorizations. See [Social Login Integration With All the Popular Social Networks in Ruby on Rails](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/10/social-login-integration-with-all-the-popular-social-networks-in-ruby-on-rails/) for a demo and code implementation for social login integration with **Twitter** + **Facebook** + **Linkedin** + **Google** + **Github**.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you're the one who has to create the logic that will link all the different social accounts (Facebook, Google, Twitter) together.

In my case, I use each user's `email` to link his different social accounts.

Comment: The problem is twitter does not give email id whereas the other two (Gmail, Facebook) gives email id. Are you using twitter?

Comment: I am. And in Twitter's case, I only let the user proceed if he provides an email. It's a solution that may be a bit bothersome to users but it was the only one I found to be able to link accounts.